# Consider the series $ ∑_{n=1}^∞ x^2+ n/n^2$ . Pick out the true statements:

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the series
$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^2+ n/n^2$ 
.
Pick out the true statements:
(a) The series converges for all real values of $x$.
(b) The series converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.
(c) The series does not converge absolutely for any real value of $x$.

---

stuck on this problem totally. please help me to solve this problem.thanks .

Comment: Do you mean $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{x^2 + n\over n^2}?$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n^2}\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^2+\frac{n}{n^2}.$$

If you inadvertently meant $(x^2+n)/n^2$, then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n^2}\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^2+n}{n^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Only (c) applies. because $\sum_{n\ge 1} {1/n}$ diverges..