# a problem on convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consider the series $ ∑_{n=1}^∞ x^2+ n/n^2$ . Pick out the true statements:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278330/consider-the-series-n-1-x2-n-n2-pick-out-the-true-statements)

Consider the series
$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n(x^2+ n)/n^2$
Pick out the true statements:
(a) The series converges for all real values of $x$.
(b) The series converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

how can I able to solve this.

Comment: Use ideas in a [very similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278330/consider-the-series-n-1-x2-n-n2-pick-out-the-true-statements) posted minutes earlier.

Comment: The terms $(-1)^n{x^2+n\over n^2}$ do not converge uniformly to $0$ on $\Bbb R$. Thus, the series can't converge uniformly on $\Bbb R$ (a series converges uniformly if and only if it is uniformly Cauchy).

Comment: Incidentally, an "alternating series" converges uniformly if the terms converge uniformly to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting up the infinite series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} (x^2 + n)/n^{2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} x^{2}/n^{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} n/n^{2} = x^2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}/n^{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}/n$$

Note that each of the last two infinite sums converges (why?) which justifies the above line read from right to left. In particular, the sum of two convergent series converges.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply alternating series test

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: I got (a).but not sure about (b)

Comment: you can use David Mitra arguments above on the comments